# Is there a way to reduce the memory of this Python code for my challenge?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, memory

Here is my code. The challenge is to take a string of numbers and get the combinations of them, and take the average of each combination. Then for each them, count the averages that is more than or equal to the limit (k).

My issue now is my code isn't passing the memory Limit of 256 MB.

Is there any tips for optimizing this code to use less memory?

```
from itertools import combinations
 
k = input().split(" ")[1]
nums_arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
 
def combs(x):
  return [c for i in range(len(x)+1) for c in combinations(x,i)][1:]
 
def avg(x):
  return map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), combs(nums_arr))
 
def condition(arr):
  return sum(map(lambda x : x >= int(k), avg(nums_arr)))
 
print(condition(nums_arr))
```

[See this for more info on question + example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqaqT.png)
[Please see this image for input format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSvsL.png)

Comment: You probably want to look up generators or generator expressions

Comment: btw, I think that both `condition()` and `avg()` should take and use a param named `arr`. You are currently relying on the global `nums_arr`.

Comment: Seeing the input constraints, I think you're supposed to use some fact/observation rather than generating all combinations

Comment: you could loop with an binary array length k representing the combination. [0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0], ... using much less memory

Comment: @quamrana Whoops I missed that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur My question requires me to generate all combinations. Sorry if I didn't provide more details.

Comment: @Turo Interesting idea! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @BenedictNeo in the question, only the count of valid sequences is required? I don't see a need to generate all sequences

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I'm sorry but may I ask what's the distinction between valid sequences and all sequences. If I find the possible combinations for a list of numbers, what would count as valid and invalid? Maybe I'm not familiar with the itertools combination function

Comment: @BenedictNeo can you add a link to the original problem?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur sorry the challenge was private and it is already closed. You can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqaqT.png for an example of the challenge tho. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `combs` should be re-written as the following equivalent generator function:

```py
def combs(arr):
    first_time = True
    for i in range(len(arr)+1):
        for c in combinations(arr, i):
            if first_time:
                first_time = False
                continue
            yield c
```

You should also incorporate the suggestion offered by @quamrana.

Comment: Thanks for this! I wanted to ask are list comprehensions generally less efficient/uses more memory? And is it possible to use generator functions for all my functions, or in this case only combs.

Comment: A list comprehension, as the name suggests, creates a list of all the items in memory. So if there are `n` combinations, you will have a list of `n` items. A generator function or generator expression, such as `combs` in the answer above, uses essentially no memory and generates each item of the combination only as you iterate the generator. `avg` returns a `map`, which behaves like a generator expression and `cond` is summing a `map` expression. So these are Okay. I assume `nums_arr` is not so large that having this as a list poses a problem.

Comment: I should add that for `nums_arr`, you really have no choice but to use a list since function `avg` needs to take its length, with `len` and you cannot do that if you used a generator expression for `nums_arr`. You would have to rewrite `avg` to iterate argument `x` to get its length and sum otherwise. But once you did that you would have nothing left to iterate for calling function `combs`.